# php token form handling

Tags: php, token

I have a token that i'm trying to check on form submission below is my token functions with the form i use to submit and then the form handling of where the token should be checked. I cannot get the token function to work any reason why?

```
<?php
function getToken()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_token']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_token'] = md5(uniqid());
    }
}

function checkToken($token)
{
    if($token != $_SESSION['user_token'])
    {
    header('location: 404.php');
    exit;
    }
}
function getTokenField()
{
    return '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$_SESSION['user_token'].'" />';
}
function destroyToken()
{
    unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
}
```

A register form named register.php which redirects to the registerscript.php page.

```
<?php getToken(); ?>
<form method="post" action="registerscript.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold;color:red">

            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
                {
                     echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['firstname'].'</p>';
                     echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['lastname'].'</p>';
                     echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['username'].'</p>';
                     echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['email'].'</p>';
                     echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['password'].'</p>';
                     echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['country'].'</p>';
                     unset($_SESSION['error']);
                }
            ?>

            </td>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="firstname">First Name</label></div></td>
            <td><input name="firstname" type="text" class="input" size="25" required /></td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></div></td>
            <td><input name="lastname" type="text" class="input" size="25" required /></td>
        </tr>           <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="username">User Name</label></div></td>
            <td><input name="username" type="text" class="input" size="25" required /></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="password">Password</label></div></td>
            <td><input name="password" type="password" class="input" size="25" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="confirmpw">Confirm Password</label></div></td>
            <td><input name="confirmpw" type="password" class="input" size="25" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="email">Email</label></div></td>
            <td><input name="email" type="email" class="input" size="25" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
            <td><select name="country">
                <option selected value="0">Select Country</option>
                    <?php
                            while ($rowCerts = $resultcategories->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<option value=\"{$rowCerts['country']}\">";
                            echo $rowCerts['country'];
                            echo "</option>";
                            }
                    ?>

            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="23"></td>
            <td><div align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!" />
            <?php echo getTokenField(); ?>
```

On the form handling on submit I want it to check the token is valid with the following code but it takes me to the 404.php as if there is no token but when i view the page source there is a token.

```
            <?php
                session_start();
                include_once('conn.php');
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    checkToken($token);
                    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
                    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
                    $username = $_POST["username"];
                    $password = $_POST["password"];
                    $confirmpw = $_POST["confirmpw"];
                    $country = $_POST["country"];

                    if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $firstname))
                        {
                             $_SESSION['error']['firstname'] = "Incorrect characters used in Firstname.<br>";
                        }
               }
```

My source code shows:

```
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!" />
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="f0de3e58dbd6196ac0f964203577abb0" />               </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you started session at the top of your PHP scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Is `$token` set at this point?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    checkToken($token);
}
```

Or should it be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    checkToken($_POST['token']);
}
```

Comment: When i check the source of the register form there is a generated token so i assume it isset?

Answer (score 0):

More likely that previous answer is right. What do you have inside conn.php file?

Try to add such string:

```
echo "--$token--$_SESSION[user_token]--";die;
```

before the line

```
header('location: 404.php');
```

and say what do you get.

Comment: could it be that because im redirecting from register.php to registerscript.php the session token is different?

Comment: i got ----f0de3e58dbd6196ac0f964203577abb0-- thing is its echoing after if($token != $_SESSION['user_token'])

Comment: So your $_SESSION["user_token"] is empty. register.php and registerscript.php is the same. Don't you change domain there, like from www.domain.com to domain.com?

Comment: why is it empty what have i not done ? Yes there on the same domain

Comment: Also check, if session is started if your form file. Possibly you just set $_SESSION variable without starting session which has no effect.

Comment: Have you posted whole register.php file? If yes, than try this: <?php session_start(); getToken(); ?>

Comment: session_start(); is at the top of every page

Comment: Add print_r($_SESSION); before getToken(); , refresh register.php 2 times and post what do you see.

Comment: if($token != $_SESSION['user_token'])
 {
  echo "--$token--";die;
  header('location: 404.php');
  exit;
 }
i get ---- if i do this.. does this mean $token is not assigned

Comment: You get ---- if you do what? I mean refresh 2 times register.php file. Not registerscript.php.

Comment: Array ( [user_token] => f0de3e58dbd6196ac0f964203577abb0 )

Comment: So there you have it. Now change echo "--$token--$_SESSION[user_token]--"; to print_r($_SESSION); (and leave die; after that). Than post what do you see there.

Comment: should it not be function checkToken('user_token') instead of function checkToken($token) as $token is undefined?

Comment: Sprry, didn't saw how many slashes are there. Try checkToken($_POST["token"]);

Comment: i get the same with printr - Array ( [user_token] => f0de3e58dbd6196ac0f964203577abb0 )

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in /home/cluster-sites/2/i/i.uk/public_html/PROJECT/functions/token.php on line 11

Comment: You get this error if you make checkToken($_POST["token"]); ?

Comment: do you mean checkToken($_POST["user_token"]);

Comment: are u talking about changing the function name to checkToken($_POST["token"]); or changing it in the registerscript

Comment: No. $_POST["token"]; Also try adding print_r($_POST); before that die; and post what you see.

Comment: That $token, which you pass to checkToken is empty. Most likely you haven't set it or did it incorrectly. And needed value is in $_POST["token"]. So you can just pass it.

Comment: I get nothing with print_r($_POST["token"]);

Comment: where do i set $token then hmm

Comment: print_r($_POST); and make checkToken($_POST["token"]);

Comment: Also you can add such line $token=$_POST["token"]; before checkToken($token);

Comment: believe that works do i assign token to post token in the register.php or registerscript.php

Comment: Only in registerscript.php. And IMO would be better to use just checkToken($_POST["token"]);